# initial position and velocity

Tags: calculus

The angle A of a heavily damped swinging door varies with time according to the law

$$A=\frac{e^{−at}−e^{−bt}}{b−a}$$,
where $a$ and $b$ are positive constants that depend on the damping, the weight of the door, and the spring.

The variable $t$ is measured in seconds, and $A$ is the angle in radians.

What is the initial (angular) position and initial angular velocity of the door at $t=0$?

how to differentiate with all constants? they make me lost, while differentiating.

Comment: for the initial angular position just calculate $A(t=0)$ (As you mentioned). For the angular velocity it's easy $\frac{dA}{dt}$. And please show us your work this is not a homework answering website

Comment: Perhaps it will be easier if you look at $A$ written like this: $$A = \frac{1}{b-a}\,(e^{-at} - e^{-bt})$$ The term at the front is a constant multiplying a function of $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $t=0$ we have the inital position:

$$
A=\dfrac{1}{b-a}(e^0-e^0)=0
$$
For the angular velocity we have:
$$
\omega=\dfrac{d}{dt}A= \dfrac{1}{b-a}\dfrac{d}{dt}(e^{-at}-e^{-bt})=\dfrac{1}{b-a}(-ae^{-at}+be^{-bt})
$$
that, for $t=0$ gives $\omega=1$